# Can I configure a custom slot type for hashtags?

Tags: amazon-lex

I want to configure AWS Lex to look for a word in the incoming questions that are starting with a `#` character. For example:

> Can you give me more information regarding the #12GBDE order?

I am not able to configure this because Lex only accepts regular expressions with the A-Z a-z 0-9 characters [according to their docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/built-in-slot-alphanumeric.html)

Is there a way around this, or is it a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your lex prompts to use the words "number", "hash", and "hashtag" before the input. That way Lex expects the user to say it, but the speech recognition engine does not have to recognize the hash as part of the order number.

In the code that looks up the order number, add a prefix of "#" if it is necessary.